# Word through Excel - How to select a portion of text?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, find

I'm working on an Excel-Word VBA code that runs through several Word files and extracts data for the Excel table (where the VBA code takes place).

In each of the Word files there will be a "tool" description followed by a reference for this tool (9 char plus a version char) like this :

[image]

This can be inline with the text, in two paragraphs like for the "tool 1", or in a table cell like the "Tool 2".... An image is included next/after the reference.

Of course, there can be more than one Tool... So, the tables follow one another, and the "plain text" will be separated by images or paragraphs.

Therefore, my goal is to extract the tool number and the reference code (which is always a different one), so that in the Excel table there will be a row for each file, a column for each tool number and the reference at the intersection of both :-)

I want to select all the text between "Tool" and the end of the reference, then it will be easy to work with it to extract the Tool number and reference.

I've already tried several things but I'm not the best one with the "find" function as you will see ^^

```
oApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory  'Going back to beginning of the word document (last search sent us to the bottom)

            With oApp.Selection.Find 'Searching for the words 'Reference : ' as the ref is just after it
                .Text = "Reference :"
                .Forward = True
                .MatchWholeWord = True
                .Execute  'Lunching the search
            End With

            RefFind = oApp.Selection.EndKey

'A piece of code is surely missing in there


            With oApp.Selection.Find 'Searching for the words 'Tool'
                .Text = "Tool"
                .Forward = False
                .MatchWholeWord = True
                .Execute
            End With
            ToolFind = oApp.Selection.HomeKey
            'ToolFind = oApp.Selection.Find.Execute  'Lunching the search
            'oApp.Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

            'oApp.Select.

'No idea what to put there... It obviously will be in a loop that isn't represented here ;-)
```

As you see, I searched for "Reference : " first, then searched back the word "Tool". 
In fact, the word "tool" can be used in the word files, but if I found the "reference : " (which is way less likely to appear), I know that the "Tool" just before is the good one :-)

So? How could I simply select that all? It's getting like a messy labyrinth in my head (I'm learning ^^, )

Comment: Do reference codes follow a certain pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Selection` for something like this is very difficult. Better to work with two `Range` objects: one for the Reference, the other for the Tool.

The code below does that, basing on the logic defined in the question, first searching Reference, then working backwards to Tool. For each search term a different `Range` object is used.

As with `Selection`, the `Range` changes to the found text. So the `Range` for the second term is set to the `Duplicate` of the found Reference before the search backwards is executed.

If this also found, then the first `Range` is extended to the end of its paragraph as well as back to the start of the second `Range`. (Note, however, that you may well want to work with the separate ranges, extending the second range to the end of its paragraph - then you have Tool and Reference already "split".)

Lastly, the first `Range` is collapsed to its end-point before the search is run again so that it begins *after* the first "find".

```
Sub FindTermBAckwardsSecondTerm()
    Dim rngFindFirst As Word.Range, rngFindSecond As Word.Range
    Dim firstTerm As String, secondTerm As String
    Dim foundFirst As Boolean, foundSecond As Boolean

    firstTerm = "Reference"
    secondTerm = "Tool"
    Set rngFindFirst = ActiveDocument.content
    Do
        With rngFindFirst.Find
            .Text = firstTerm
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            foundFirst = .Execute
            If foundFirst Then
                Set rngFindSecond = rngFindFirst.Duplicate
                rngFindSecond.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                With rngFindSecond.Find
                    .Text = secondTerm
                    .Forward = False
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    foundSecond = .Execute
                    If foundSecond Then
                        rngFindFirst.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
                        rngFindFirst.Start = rngFindSecond.Start
                        Debug.Print rngFindFirst
                    End If
                End With
            End If
            rngFindFirst.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        End With
     Loop While foundFirst
End Sub
```