# Words VBA: Creating Range using positions of searched words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following Problem: We wrote a specification with many external sources like XML Files etc. and every time the XML file changes, we have to modify the corresponding XML part in the specification. Actually, I managed to insert the Text of the XML File every time the document will be opened. My Problem is now that I can’t search after the already inserted XML code which is outdated and should be replaced by this new one.

After some useful hints from @Cindy Master I would adopt my code like this (code: one of my used functions which contains the difficult selection of the old xml which I can’t manage to work):

```vb
Function wasUpdated(strFilename As String, XMLStart As String, XMLEnd As String) As Boolean

    Dim new_xml As String
    FileToString new_xml, strFilename

    Dim range_start As Long
    Dim range_end As Long

    Dim start_point As Range
    Dim end_point As Range

    Set start_point = ActiveDocument.Range
    Set end_point = ActiveDocument.Range

    start_point.Find.Execute(XMLStart)
    end_point.Find.Execute(XMLEnd)

    range_start = start_point.Start
    range_end = end_point.End

    Set rngParagraphs = ActiveDocument.Range( _
        Start:=range_start, _
        End:=range_end)

    old_xml = rngParagraphs.Text

    If new_xml = old_xml Then
        wasUpdated = False
    Else
        wasUpdated = True
    End If
End Function
```

The Problem with this code is that the `start_point.Find.Execute(XMLStart)` function can’t find the searched word. Strangely enough, the `Selection.Find.Execute(XMLStart)` works. Is there a difference between `Range.Find` and `Selection.Find` which I don’t know?

Comment: If you use `Range.Find` the search `Range` object will move to the "found" range. Same as a `Selection` will if you were to use `Selection.Find`. Note that it's also possible to use `Find.Replace`. Try it as a user, first, to see how it works. Then record a macro to get the "bare bones" code. If you need further help, come back and post a new question with the recorded macro code and we can show you how to refine it for your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
So, for example this code should display a message box with the found text, right?
`…
Dim start_point As Range

Set start_point = ActiveDocument.Range
test = start_point.Find.Execute(selectionName)

MsgBox start_point.Text      //returns whole document and not the searched test
MsgBox "Range:" & test      //returns false

test = Selection.Find.Execute(selectionName)
MsgBox "Selection:" & test      //returns true` 

Only the “Slection.Find” method finds the searched word and return true. “Range.Find” returns false (see example above).

Comment: Sorry for this horrible formatted answer. I’m new to Stackoverflow, is there a way to write an readable answer?

Comment: LIng, I'm sorry - I should have mentioned you can use the [edit] link below your question to add the code directly to the question. That will look much better :-) Good on you, though, for finding the `backtick`!

Comment: See if the proposed approach in this Answer isn't what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477990/word-through-excel-how-to-select-a-portion-of-text/57493466#57493466

Comment: Thank you for the link, the problem seems to be almost similar but I have some problems with the `Range.Find` function as described in my updated description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I was able to solve my problem.
Here is the code that looks for the XML part and returns it as a Range object:

```
Private Function getXMLRange1(XMLStart As String):

    'TEST
    Dim test As Boolean

    Dim XMLEnd As String
    XMLEnd = "</order>"

    Dim range_start As Long
    Dim range_end As Long

    Dim start_point As Range
    Dim start_pointNext As Range
    Dim end_point As Range

    Set start_point = ActiveDocument.Range


    test = start_point.Find.Execute(XMLStart)
'    MsgBox start_point.Text
'    MsgBox "Range start:" & test

    start_point.Move Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2
    Set end_point = ActiveDocument.Range(start_point.Start, ActiveDocument.Range.End)


    test = end_point.Find.Execute(XMLEnd)
'    MsgBox end_point.Text
'    MsgBox "Range end:" & test


    range_start = start_point.End
    range_end = end_point.End


    Set getXMLRange1 = ActiveDocument.Range( _
        Start:=range_start, _
        End:=range_end)

End Function
```

Range.Find and Selection.Find behave the equal way.